# Show current layer and hide all other layers in Adobe Fireworks

Tags: fireworks

I've been learning how to use Adobe Fireworks since I'd like to use some of the beneficial features such as better png compression compared with photoshop. In Photoshop on the layers palette it is straightforward to just turn off all the other layers in the open document by option clicking on the eye icon on the layer. However, this doesnt work in Fireworks. Is there a quick way of turning off all layers apart from the one the user is working on?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great solution, but I can't seem to find any proper way to do this either, besides option clicking the eye and then clicking again to turn the chosen layer back on.

If you make a text file with this script and save it as "Hide Other Layers.jsf", you can drop it into your Fireworks *Configuration / Commands* folder. If it's in the right folder, it should show up in the *Commands* menu, and then you can add a keyboard shortcut to run it:

```
fw.getDocumentDOM().setLayerVisible(-1, -1, false, true);
fw.getDocumentDOM().setLayerVisible(-1, -1, true, false);
```

That will hide every layer, then reveal whichever layer you currently have selected.

Comment: Ah, I should clarify that this script does only work on *Layers*, and not the elements within a layer folder, so if you only have "Layer 1" with some shapes inside it, this won't do anything to those. If I work out how to do that I'll update my answer though.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I'm unsure whether to use Fireworks now since I've used Photoshop for years. The simplicity of Fireworks, the multi page features and the almost halved file sizes of png8 files may make the limitations bearable.